# Getting java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket when trying to get sequence next value from jdbc driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using **oracle 19.0.0.0.0** and **jdbc8** version **19.3.0** to connect to the database.

I am inserting data into a table. Before insert, fetching next sequence value for the serial number column. The code run fine for some time and throw below exception while getting next sequence value.

The same code is running on another server and connected to different database. It is working fine. This issue id only from a particular database.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:784)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:429)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:407)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:983)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3713)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1167)
        at com.agnity.clients.RouteLinkDbManager.getNextSequenceValue(RouteLinkDbManager.java:765)
        at com.agnity.clients.RouteLinkDbManager.addCPR(RouteLinkDbManager.java:256)
        at com.agnity.handlers.RecordHandler.processActionCPR(RecordHandler.java:280)
        at com.agnity.handlers.RecordHandler.processEventArray(RecordHandler.java:147)
        at com.agnity.handlers.RecordHandler.processRecords(RecordHandler.java:63)
        at com.agnity.routelink.SomosDownloadApplication.main(SomosDownloadApplication.java:135)

The query used: String sqlIdentifier = "select " + sequenceName + ".NEXTVAL from dual";
```

We tried running the same code to connect to another database and it is working fine.

Comment: That error suggests to me a problem at the database end.  Has a DBA looked into the various logs in the database (e.g. the alert log) to see if there are any clues as to what is going on?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not able to see any log/ alert in dump files. Could you please suggest me the exact file to check the error? Does the Restart database work here ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're looking in dump files.  The alert log would be the first place to look, and where to find that is described at https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Alert_log .  It's _possible_ that restarting the database _might_ clear the problem, but of course it might not.